# Почему в одном случае есть запятая, а во втором ее нет?

Tags: пунктуация

Я знаю, что в предложении ***"хочу быть как мама"*** запятой нет.
А почему есть в предложении ***"плакал, как младенец"***?

Answer (score 2):

Хочу быть как мама — сравнительный оборот в составе сказуемого не обособляется.

Оборот «как младенец» может **обособляться или не обособляться** в зависимости от структуры предложения.

(1) Плакал как младенец – **необособленное обстоятельство** (плакать по-детски), ударение падает только на оборот.

(2) Плакал,  как младенец – **обособленное сравнение**, ударение падает и на глагол, и не оборот (плакать, как плачут младенцы).

Примеры:

Лавр очнулся, увидев хижину, подле которой сидел на толстом пне дерева старец в волосяной одежде ― и **плакал как младЕнец.** [А. Ф. Вельтман. Кощей бессмертный. Былина старого времени (1833)]

Мне казалось, что вся природа радовалась со мною, ― я **плАкал, как младЕнец**… [Н. М. Карамзин. Письма русского путешественника (1793)]

Answer (score 1):

*Хочу быть как мама* -запятой нет, потому что это составное именное сказуемое. (Так же, как *хочу быть мамой*)

```
 А почему есть в предложении "плакал, как младенец"?
```

Потому что здесь явное сравнение:сравнивается чей-то плач с плачем  младенца. Это совершенно разные предложения.